# Using JavaScript Cookies as Global Variables

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a problem using JavaScript cookies as global variable. Basically I've set the cookie with the attribute prev to store a value on a jsp page.

Then on another jsp page, I will try to obtain the value. However I do not get the value. I always got the wrong value.

The two jsp page are abc.jsp and xyz.jsp. Both jsp pages have a <%@ include file='cookies.jsp'%>

This is the content inside cookies.jsp. It is the same code as W3school example.

```
<script>
/*Code For Setting Cookies*/
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
    var x=getCookie("prev");
    if (x!=null) //cookie is set
      {
        //do nothing
      }
    else 
      {
        setCookie("prev",0,365); //set to null
      }
} //end of code for setting cookies
</script>
```

Most importantly, I tried to use getCookie() and setCookie(). It seems to set the cookies locally on the page but not transferring values across pages. May I know what happen?

Please prompt me for more questions if you need more clue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set path `;path=/` in the cookie to access it in all pages.

```
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value+";path=/";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC2109](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109) § 4.3.1, the "Path" of a cookie *defaults to the path of the request URL that generated the Set-Cookie response, up to, but not including, the right-most /*.

That means you're missing `; PATH=/` from your cookie setting function:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null)
                                 ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString())
                                + "; path=/";
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Consider strongly not copying/pasting code that you find on the Internet.
relevant information is well

Comment: @Ferrino - and the semicolon (;)